# Using "or" statements with strings in an if statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement

So I want to make a code that categorizes words to match it with a phrase.
`catString` is a string inputted by the user.  I want it to execute the rest of the code only if this input is fire or smoke.

Here's the line I'm having trouble with:

```
if(catString = "fire" || "smoke" );
```

Comment: `if (catString.equals("fire") || catString.equals("smoke")) doStuff();`

Comment: You can search the net (for instance, this if statements) before posting questions here. Just an advise. =)

Answer (score 6):

You need to repeat the `catString =`. However, you **should not be using `==` (not `=`, the assignment operator) to compare strings**. Use `.equals()`. So that would look like:

```
if(catString.equals("fire") || catString.equals("smoke"));
```

Comment: Also equals when doing a comparison should be `==` not `=` in general. The reason you don't use it with a string is because you `==` compares the address in memory instead of if the charters of the string are equal.

Comment: @ansible That's true, I didn't see that at first glance (that they were using `=`. I edited that into the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`if (catString.equals("fire") || catString.equals("smoke"))`

Note that a single = is NOT a comparison operation. It will assign `catString`, not what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java):

```
if(catString.equals("fire") || catString.equals("smoke"))
    // do something
```

By the way, if you're testing for reference equality, use `==` not `=` (which is used in assignment).

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 if(catString.equals("fire") || catString.equals("smoke"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `equalsIgnoreCase` so that the user can type it whatever case he wants and still matching the `catString`.

e.g.

```
if("fire".equalsIgnoreCase(catString) || "smoke".equalsIgnoreCase(catString))
```

Note: You must first put the "fire" and "smoke" before the equalsIgnoreCase to avoid NullPointerException.